# My Xamarin app keeps crashing due to Databinding(Basic Databinding)

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, xamarin-entry

I was trying to use Databinding in my Xamarin app. After implementing, just like the many instructions suggest, it just always crashes while loading the app. Without any real error message.

I guess I did something wrong, but after hours of searching I didn't find any clue to solve my problem.

[This is the text inside the terminal:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bT5Kn.png)

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TippAssist.ViewModels"
             x:Class="TippAssist.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MainPageViewmodel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding test}"></Label>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TippAssist
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainPageViewmodel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TippAssist.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewmodel : BindableObject
    {
        public string test {
            get => test;
            set
            {
                if (value == test)
                    return;
                test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainPageViewmodel()
        {
            this.test = "IT WORKS!";
        }
    }
}
```

I would be really happy if anyone is able to tell me the mistake I made.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app gets crashed, since you're assigning the value to the same public property. Create a private property "_test" and use it as follows:

```
    private string _test;
    public string test
    {
        get => _test;
        set
        {
            if (value == _test)
                return;
            _test = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, seems like i created a loop.
It does work now, thank you very much :)

Comment: If you consider this as solution to your issue, please upvote mark the answer as accepted. Thank you.